# both of my parents are dead or both of my parents were dead

Tags: grammar, tense

*"Both of my parents are dead"* or *"both of my parents were dead"*? Which example is grammatically correct?  Are
*"are dead"* and *"were dead"* the same or not?

Comment: Welcome! This can't be answered right now. Past tense and present tense are both useful. Please use the "Edit" button to add to the question to say more about what meaning you want.

Comment: Let me answer with intentional irony,  "It depends on the context."

Answer (score 22):

If you are speaking of a fact, use the present tense. If you are telling a story set in the past, you can use the past tense.

> I left my home town when I was 21. Both my parents were dead and I had no other close relatives.

Comment: Alternatively to make the point: "Both of my parents are dead by now" vs "both of my parents were dead by the time I went to school".

Comment: "Both of my parents are dead by now" is not good English.

Comment: @deep64blue - Why do you say that? It's perfectly grammatical - perhaps not a very likely thing for someone to say, but Mark was using it to explain the different uses of the tenses.

Comment: @KateBunting Grammatical, but not as idiomatic as "Both of my parents have died by now."

Comment: @Barmar - the '...by now' is superflous and also not idiomatic. If both parents are known to be dead then it's clear that they are dead by 'now'. So "Both of my parents have died." is sufficient.  If there's a case of doubt (i.e. parents were on a plane that crashed / ship that sunk - but death is not confirmed) then "Both of my parents will be dead by now" could be used in some contexts but note that implies a prediction of fact not an actual fact.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know what variety of English you're used to, but in the UK "Both of my parents have died by now." are the sort of thing one would say walking away from the wreckage of the family car.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd On this side of the pond I think it would be more normal say "Both of my parents are dead now" or "Both of my parents have died now." I don't think many would say "by now".

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I'm also English (having lived in the North and the South West), and I've never heard "by now" added to anything except as an indication of an event that likely would have occurred by the time spoken (and the speaker is not aware of it definitely having happened), not something which has already (definitely) happened. In either case, I think it is not idiomatic English to say "have... by now." It should be "would have... by now" or "could have... by now." **Example:** "My mum would have died by now [due to age, if not for her early death...]"

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd To my AmE ear, "... are [X] by now" without further clarification has a speculative quality - a statement that the speaker assumes to be true, but does not know for certain.

Comment: @deep64blue "I opened the airlock door remotely 3 minutes ago. Both of my parents are dead by now".

Comment: Native English speakers would say  "I opened the airlock door remotely 3 minutes ago. Both of my parents will be dead by now".

Comment: @deep64blue Not this one (left-Pondian). Both sound okay and there is a slight difference in emphasis.